# Python Tk IndexError:list index out of range

Tags: python, tkinter

Ok, I'm using python and tk to write a program. I need it to open a file and read one line, print it, then read the next line and print it. I first use:

```
self.wordlist = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(mode='rb',title='Select a wordlist')
```

In another part of the code I have:

```
num = 1
while True:
    line = self.wordlist.readlines()[num].strip()
    print line
    num = num + 1
```

When I run this it returns:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\hashgui.py", line 109, in hashcrack_command
    line = self.wordlist.readlines()[num].strip()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It prints the first line but stops on the second? Why?

Comment: Calling `readlines()` more than once is unnecessary. And it won't work, because after the first call the file cursor is at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

The count in Python starts at `0`, so it should be `num = 0`. The first line is at `file.readlines()[0]`.

However, this way looks better:

```
for line in self.wordlist:
    print line
```